# Media Foundation video decoding

Tags: windows, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

I'm using Media Foundation and the IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback to playback video files and render them to a texture. I am able to get video samples in the IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback::OnProcessSample method, but those samples are compressed. I have way less samples than I have pixels in my render target. [According to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb250371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the media session should load any decoder that is needed (if available), but that does not seem to be the case. Even if I create the decoder and add it to the topology myself, the video samples are still compressed. Is there anything in particular I am missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you configure the MF classes?

Comment: I agree.  A bit more info is needed. If you wish to have uncompressed samples, why are you grabbing it from the sink instead of the source?  Unless the sink has an output stream with a media type which will not involve an encoder.